# DolphinDB: Find records only exist in one table but not other

Tags: sql, dolphindb, drop-duplicates

I have two tables, *new* (shared table) and *old* (regular in-memory table), each with less than 10,000 rows. Both tables contain columns “a“ and “b“, and values in the "a" columns are unique. I want to compare the two columns to find records that only exist in table *new*.

The only method I know is to append all records from the table *new* to the table *old* and then use `isDuplicated` to remove duplicates. I'm wondering if there's a more efficient method.

Answer (score 1):

Simply to use `not in` when values in the "a" columns are unique:

```
select * from t1 where t1.a not in t2.a
```

Answer (score 1):

Apply a `where` condition where the function `makeKey` is used to combine the values of two columns into unique keys for faster filtering, such as `where makeKey(a, b) not in makeKey(old.a, old.b)`. Refer to the following script:

```
tmp = table(1 3 4 5 6 as a, take(`A`B, 5) as b, rand(10.0, 5) as val)
share tmp as new
old = table(2 3 4 7 8 as a, take(`A`B, 5) as b, rand(10.0, 5) as val)
select * from new where makeKey(a, b) not in makeKey(old.a, old.b)
```